# When does URL redirect happen?

Tags: java, redirect, httpurlconnection

I have a URL that redirects to another one, that redirects to another one, and I'm trying to get the end domain. I thought that the redirection would happen when connecting, but running this code tells me otherwise:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(resolveEndDomain("http://goo.gl/ELHEjl"));
    }

    private static String resolveEndDomain(String deepLink)
    {
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = null;
        try
        {
            httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(deepLink).openConnection();
            //httpConnection.getResponseCode();  
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return httpConnection.getURL().getHost();
    }
```

So, if I run it, it will just give me `goo.gl`. But if I uncomment the line to get the response code, it goes and fetches it from the end domain, and prints `www.thomann.de`. The same occurs if I use `getHeaderFields()`, `getContent()` or similar, but `connect()` doesn't seem to help. I'm not interested in any of those responses so, how can I make it go and resolve the redirections? When does the connection effectively occur?

Comment: A redirect normally is a response of the server telling the client to look elsewhere. So the redirect normally is sent on the server side but the client then has to follow it. If you check the http status code you should get a 301 or 302, which indicates that the response contains the location you're being redirected to.

Comment: What is wrong with `www.thoman.de`. I would say that it is the value you are looking for, isn't it?

Comment: @Thomas No, the code is only 301 if first I call `HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false)`. But without specifying false, it should follow the link automatically, and in fact it does when I call `getResponseCode()`, which then gives me a 200.

Comment: @SJuan76 Yes, but I want to have that without calling any get method, since I'm not interested in any of that data. And I want to understand when does the redirection happen.

Comment: Well, since the redirect is issued on the server side you'll need to make a request first, which happens when calling those methods you're not interested in. You could disallow following redirects and get the domain from the 30x response yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As for your question, the redirect happens when the server being connected replies with a 301 or 302 HTTP Status Code. Note that Status Code are part of the answer from the server, so you must have actually requested the resource from it (usually with `connect()`).

As you have already found, `HttpURLConnection` usually handles the part of checking for the redirect Status Code and redirects you to the URL provided as part of the redirect response (up to a maximum of redirections, I am not sure where that limit is defined).

You could set `followsRedirects` to `false` and interpret the HTTP headers yourself to find if you are going to be redirected or not, but until you get a `2X` Status code (or `4XX` -not found, forbidden- or `5XX` -server error-) you will not be sure if the URL you are being redirected to is the last one.

For example, you could connect to `http://goo.gl/ELHEjl` and find that it redirects you to `http://www.bit.ly/s34314313`. But then, unless you connect to that URL and get a not 3XX Status Code, you cannot be sure if connecting to `http://www.bit.ly/s34314313` is the final resource location or it will just redirect you again.